# Get prompt back after running a python script in background

Tags: python, shell

I am executing a python script in background mode from a shell script.
The script is running fine but I am unable to get the prompt back until I manually press enter from keyboard. I want to avoid the manual interaction.

I already tried running the script like `echo "/n" | python script.py &`

I also tried:

```
python3 /simulators/utils/reboot_ap.py $input 2>&1 &`

python3 script.py $input 2>&1 &
```

Comment: That last ampersand should put the script in the background and return you to the shell prompt. If you're having problems, perhaps the python script itself is expecting some input, and you can't run it non-interactively.

Comment: Strictly this is a Linux question rather than a Python question. Python just happens to be the process. (We can't know whether the Python script itself is expecting some input, unless you post it)

Comment: please edit the question to specify additional info. Ideally, try using a very simple python script (hello world!) instead of your original python script, and test if the issue still persists. Eliminate potential issues and then try to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Try `echo -e "\n"| python script.py &`

Comment: My python script is not expecting any input.The scripts just sleeps for 10 seconds. I do get my prompt back when I run it without & but only after 10 seconds and I don't want that thats why I ran with &. All the input it needed is provided in command line when i run the script.

Comment: Okay I figured out something. My python script had some print statements. Once I commented them, I got the prompt back. Does anyone have any idea about this behavior?